# Comparing csv files with -like in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two csv files, each that contain a PATH column.  For example:

**CSV1.csv**

```
PATH,Data,NF
\\server1\folderA,1,1
\\server1\folderB,1,1
\\server2\folderA,1,1
\\server2\folderB,1,1
```

**CSV2.csv**

```
PATH,User,Access,Size
\\server1\folderA\file1,don,1
\\server1\folderA\file2,don,1
\\server1\folderA\file3,sue,1
\\server2\folderB\file1,don,1
```

What I'm attempting to do is create a script that will result in separate csv exports based on the paths in CSV1 such that the new files contain file values from CSV2 that match.  For example, from the above, I'd end up with 2 results:

**result1.csv**

```
\\server1\folderA\file1,don,1
\\server1\folderA\file2,don,1
\\server1\folderA\file3,sue,1
```

**result2.csv**

```
\\server2\folderB\file1,don,1
```

Previously I've used a script lime this when the two values are exact:

```
$reportfile = import-csv $apireportoutputfile -delimiter ';' -encoding unicode
$masterlist = import-csv $pathlistfile

foreach ($record in $masterlist)
    {
    $path=$record.Path
    $filename = $path -replace '\\','_'
    $filename = '.\Working\sharefiles\' + $filename + '.csv'

    $reportfile | where-object {$_.path -eq $path} | select FilePath,UserName,LastAccessDate,LogicalSize | export-csv -path $filename
    write-host "     Creating files list for $path"  -foregroundcolor red -backgroundcolor white
    }
```

however since the two path values are not the same, it returns nothing.  I found a -like operator but am not sure how to use it in this code to get the results I want.  where-object is a filter while -like ends up returning a true/false.  Am I on the right track?  Any ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$ht = @{}
Import-Csv csv1.csv |
  foreach { $ht[$_.path] = New-Object collections.arraylist }

Import-Csv csv2.csv |
  foreach { 
            $path = $_.path | Split-Path -Parent
            $ht[$path].Add($_) > $null
          }

$i=1
$ht.Values |
 foreach { if ($_.count)
            {
             $_ | Export-Csv "result$i.csv" -NoTypeInformation
             $i++
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
$1=ipcsv .\csv1.CSV
$2=ipcsv .\csv2.CSV
$equal = diff ($2|select @{n='PATH';e={Split-Path $_.PATH}}) $1 -Property PATH -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru
0..(-1 + $equal.Count) | %{%{$i = $_}{
     $2 | ?{ (Split-Path $_.PATH) -eq $equal[$i].PATH } | epcsv ".\Result$i.CSV"
}}
```